# AVD not opening in Android Studio

Tags: android

I recently installed Android studio and the first time around AVD worked fine and the emulator was up and running no problem with that. But when I turned off my computer and booted it up again. But now when i try to open avd the following error message is displayed

[image: Error Details]

when i reinstalled the android studio the same thing happens again,for the first time around it works but second time around the same error message comes.
Not able to find solutions over the internet as well.

Comment: Have you tried running Android Studio as Administrator?

Comment: I am glad it is working, since this helped to solve your problem, I have added it as an answer. Please mark it as accepted as to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem that many people have faced. The `Access Denied` is indicating that Android Studio is trying to access files that require elevated privileges.

To solve this error, right click your `Android Studio` launcher, and click `Run as Administrator`.